# Google hangouts v2.3 add voice call functionality

Tags: android, google-api, google-voice, google-hangouts

Now we can use Google hangout v2.3 for android make voice call.

But I wish I can receive call without SIM card but using WiFi, it seems now Google voice only forward the call to Google voice number to the bind phone number!

Is it possible to receive Google voice call without SIM card。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detail steps:

1. Download hangouts from GooglePlay.
2. Download "hangouts dialer" from GooglePlay.
3. Enable "incoming phone calls" from "hangouts->menu->settings->your@gmail.com->Incoming phone calls".
4. Then you can receive call without SIM card in WiFi network.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a settings in hangout to enable incoming call.why not enable it by default?